# web crawler/spider using vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-crawler

I am looking for a way to automate a task which is very time consuming. We have manufacturer name and product number which we search on web to find the site that has both the information or rather search for manufacture or the vendor sites and use the information on the link to populate relevant fields in our database.

Searching process manually consumes lots of time, what i am looking for is for a tool which can take name and product # as input go on web and search for sites which matches the input and dump the links for those.

Can anyone help me here!

Comment: just an example of manufacturer name and product ID: "AJAX TOCCO MAGNETHERMIC" "6641-0158-001 RSB"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve requires quite a bit of work and I'm afraid you didn't provide enough information for me to dive into details. However, in broadlines, a simple crawling algorithm would require the following steps:

- create an instance of [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for the required url. If you need to perform a POST request, use [GetRequestStream()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method to populate the body.
- call [GetResponse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on the request to get the response from server. Use [GetResponseStream()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to read the HTML markup from the response;
- use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to iterate through DOM nodes and select required data.
- use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what is the difference between what a broswer sends and what your application sends.
- last but not least, should you encounter a problem that you cannot solve or don't know the answer to - you already know how to use [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) :)

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I am new to .net if you can provide me an example for the usage it would be a good starting point.

Comment: if you can guide me how to attach file here so that I can share an example of what i am looking for

Comment: @user1688170, I don't know how to upload files on StackOverflow. I have prepared a demo crawler as a starting point for your project but I don't know where to upload the files... Also, the project is in C#.

Comment: I have uploaded the project on 4shared. Here is the link http://www.4shared.com/zip/xbGS0Qe-/DemoCrawler.html

Comment: I am downloading it right now, I shall get back to you once I go through your program. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi i have gone through the program. It close to what I am looking for however just one thing it picks up what ever the search page shows. Would it be possible to pick only those links which has the entire search criteria match and ignore the rest

Comment: @user1688170, of course it would be possible - that would be the implementation of your business logic.